# Convert every date to epoch timestamp text/JSON

Tags: bash, mongodb, timestamp, epoch, iso8601

I'm receiving some JSON files through a git repo I need to feed into a database.

Is there any command line script/utility so I can convert every date in the json fields from ISO 8601 (example: `2014-11-18T23:00:00.000Z`) to its timestamp/unix epoch equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used to go from timestamp to ISODate, hope you find this helpful to get what you want.

```
/usr/bin/mongo mydb --eval 
"db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
doc.timestamp = new ISODate(new Date(doc.timestamp).toISOString());
db.collection.save(doc)
});"
```

Also, use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Good luck!